# Database table with field of type date not allowed in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, compatibility

I am trying to create a table with a database field of type `DATE` in SQL Server 2008 R2, but every time I try, I get this message:

> Column, parameter, or variable #10: Cannot find data type date.

Now I know this datatype is permitted with 2008 r2, so what is going on?

I am trying to create this table within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What compatibility level are you using?

Comment: Excellent question.   The compatibility level is 90 which I know is 2005.   But now when I try to change the compatibility level from the database properties box, there is no choice 100.    And yest this is 2008 R2.

Comment: Is this an existing database the you have upgraded to SQL 2008R2? It is possible that it _can't_ be upgraded without being modified first.

Comment: I think you are right.   Trying that now.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem.    When the old database was modified, everything started to work.   Oded, if you would post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "the old database was modified"? Even if the database was in 90 compatibility mode, you wouldn't have received the error in the question, since you *can* use DATE on 2008/2008 R2 even if the database is in lower compatibility mode. I think you were still connecting to a SQL Server 2005 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are running against a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance? Is it possible that you are using the SQL Server 2008 R2 version of Management Studio, but connecting to SQL Server 2005? What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` yield?

Comment: I am thinking the OP may have upgraded an existing database without going through the upgrade advisor and as such may still be using some features that are not forwards compatible to SQL Server 2008 R2 and therefore can't change the compatibility level. What do you think?

Comment: @Oded I can't think of any setting that wouldn't let you TRY - in other words how would the UI in Management Studio know that it can't offer 100? (And also what happens if you use ALTER DATABASE instead of the SSMS crutch?) It seems the simpler answer is that he is either not connected to the instance he thinks he is, or it hasn't been upgraded like he thinks it has.

Comment: What about things like syntax that is no longer supported? Things like `*=` syntax for left outer joins? Or using table and column aliases in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Those kinds of things will cause runtime errors, they won't prevent compat level changes at the database level. That ALTER statement doesn't parse your entire code base.

Comment: Fair enough. I still wonder what the OP meant by modifying the old database though...

Comment: I honestly believe they were still connecting to a 2005 database. There's no other explanation I can think of where the date data type couldn't be found. As I said before, try it - backward compat level doesn't prevent new data types from being used, it actually only affects the ability to use certain syntax (and this works both ways - it can allow you to use old syntax like *= and prevent new syntax like function calls inside a TVF arg list).

Comment: I believe you... your reputation precedes you ;)